# Return count of numbers with freq greater than some queries after performing instructions

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, hashmap

Recently I was working on a problem and I could not solve it within time constraints. The question is as follows:

**Problem:**
Bob currently has N empty stacks numbered from 1 to N. He does the following M times: Select 2 two numbers L and R and add one stone to each of the stacks [L,L+1,...R] At the end of these M operations, he would like to answer Q queries: How many of the stacks have at least H stones in them?

Input Format

First line contains N - number of stacks.

Second line contains M - number of operations.

Each of the next M lines consists of two space separated integers L and R.

Followed by integer Q - number of queries.

Each of next Q lines contain a single integer H.

**Constraints:**
1 ≤ N ≤ 1000000,
1 ≤ M ≤ 1000000,
1 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ N,
1 ≤ Q ≤ 1000000,
1 ≤ H ≤ N,

My approach was as follows:

```
int main(){
    int n, m, l, r, q, h;
    cin >> n >> m;
    
    vector<int>nums(n,0);

    // processing vector based on instructions
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        cin >> l >> r; 
        for(int j=l-1; j<r; j++)
            nums[j]++;
    }
    //storing freq in map
    map<int, int, greater<int>>count;
    for(auto x: nums)
        count[x]++;
   
    // getting no. of queries
    cin >> q;
    vector<pair<int, int>>queries(q);
    for(int i=0; i<q; i++){
        cin >> h;//query height
        queries[i] = make_pair(h, i);
    }
    
    sort(queries.begin(), queries.end(), greater<int>());
    
    vector<int> res(q,0);
    
    int q_index=0;
    int c = 0;
    for(auto&[key, val]:count){
        while(k<q && key < queries[q_index].first){
            res[queries[q_index].second] = c;
            q_index++;
        }
        c+=val;
        if(k == q){
            break;
        }
    }
    
    for(int x: res)cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This works but fails for large test cases. What should be the approach to solve problems like these?
TIA!

Comment: This reads like it's from some contest/challenge/competitive coding/hacking site. Is it? If your goal is to learn C++, you won't learn anything there. In nearly all cases, like this one, the correct solution is based on a mathematical or a programming trick. If you don't know what the trick is and attempt to code a brute-force approach, the program runs slow and fails for that reason. If you're trying to learn C++, you won't learn anything from meaningless online contest sites [but only from a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You're not meant to literally translate the description into code, you're meant to think about the problem and figure out a way to achieve the same result in a less computationally expensive way. This one seems pretty easy, you just have to accept that there's no non-algorithmic trick (e.g. micro-optimization) that will make this fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem might be the `std::map` in addition to your O(N^2) loop.

Totally untested code

```cpp
  int main(){
    int n, m, l, r, q, h;
    cin >> n >> m;
    
    vector<int>nums(n,0);

    // processing vector based on instructions
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        cin >> l >> r; 
        nums[l-1]++;
        nums[r-1]--;
        // saving O(N^2)
        //for(int j=l-1; j<r; j++)
        //    nums[j]++;
    } // O(N) down from O(N^2)

    //storing freq in map --- This costs O(N K + N lg N) but the K is crushing as its allocations
    //map<int, int, greater<int>>count;
    //for(auto x: nums)
    //    count[x]++;
    
    // add up the real height for each stack
    std::partial_sum(nums.begin(), nums.end(), nums.begin()); // O(N)
    std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end()); // use radex sort instead if timelimit exceeded
    
    // getting no. of queries
    cin >> q;
    //vector<pair<int, int>>queries(q);
    vector<int>queries(q);
    for(int i=0; i<q; i++){
        cin >> h; //query height
        queries[i] = h;
    }
    
    vector<int> res(q,0);

    std::transform(queries.begin(), queries.end(), res.begin(), [&](int q){
      auto i = std::lower_bound(nums.begin(), nums.end(), q); // binary search O(lg N)
      return std::(i, nums.end());
    } // O(N lg N)
    
    for(int x: res)cout << x <<  "\r\n";//endl; // nevar use endl unless you really need it.
    return 0;
  }
```

Add some const, constexp etc. to make it potentially better.

Radex sort is O(N) but the K for startup is problematic, and the code to write it is none trivial.

A good question is if your solution of sorting the queries and then placing it in the correct order by using .second is better.